# Can the Ecto schema field name be different from the column name?

Tags: elixir, ecto

I've got a legacy database that I'm trying access using `Ecto`.  In it, there's an `orders` table with an `order_status_id` column.  `order_status_id` maps to a set of constants in the legacy system.

I'd like to have the `MyApp.Order` struct contain an `order_status` field instead, which has a custom type that converts the integer IDs to meaningful atoms.  I've got the custom type working, but I can't figure out how to map a field named `order_status` to a column named `order_status_id`.

The legacy system is still online and using the database, so changing the DB schema is not an option.  Is there any way to get this working?

Answer (score 8):

I'm not sure if it was possible when the question was first asked, but it is possible now (Elixir 1.5).  See https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Schema.html
In particular the `@field_source_mapper` and `:source` options.  The `:source` option is pretty easy -- just include it in your `schema` definition something like this:

```
  schema "orders" do

    field :foo, :string, [source: :legacy_foo_db_column]
    field :status, :integer, [source: :order_status]

  end
```

In the above example, the existing database table has columns named "legacy_foo_db_column" and "order_status", but internally in the Elixir app, the schema and changeset etc. will use attributes named "foo" and "status"

Answer (score 1):

I think, it is currently not possible to simply associate model field with different column name.

If you really want to use name `order_status`, you can create additional [virtual field](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Schema.html). Those fields are not persisted to database. Then your `cast` function should be responsible for changing `order_status_id` based on params.

```
def changeset(model, params \\ :empty) do
  model
  |> cast(params, @required_fields, @optional_fields)
  |> put_order_status_id
end

defp put_order_status_id(changeset) do
  case changeset do
    %Ecto.Changeset{valid?: true, changes: %{order_status: status}} ->
      put_change(changeset, :order_status_id, id_from_status(status))
    _ ->
      changeset
  end
end
```

In theory, you can also use changeset function to do the opposite operation: set `order_status` based on `order_status_id`, but it adds complexity.

In my opinion, the best solution would be to simply accept `order_status_id` name.

Comment: My understanding is that `changeset\2` is only run when creating or persisting a record.  I don't think this solution would populate the `order_status` field when loading a record from the database.

Comment: That is true, but look at all the code examples even from generators. You should always use changesets before accessing database. When writing to it, changesets provide validation for all things that don't need to access db and friendly error messages for database constraints. When reading from database, you should also use changeset: `model = Repo.get(Model, id) changeset = Model.changeset(model)`